# on change for a button to present a list?

Tags: ios, button, swiftui

can we use on change for a button to present a list within the same view ? I am a beginner

```
struct ViewMe: View {
var body: some View {

    Button (action:{
                
            },label:{
                Text("Search")
            })
          // can we do on change here to appear a list
       }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are you simply trying to hide and show a list?

Comment: yes I am trying to show while search and get a result and hide when there is no result

Comment: You need to do an MRE like above with the view set up and working except for the list hiding and showing, but there are several ways of doing it. The best choice will depend upon how you have your view set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information you gave me, here is some code that should work with explanations for each part:

```
struct ContentView: View {

  //Your variable. @State makes it reload the view when changed.
  @State var listIsShowing = false


  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      //Your Button
      Button (action:{
        //Sets variable to true, showing list
        listIsShowing = true
      },label:{
        Text("Search")
      })

      //To put the button at the top
      Spacer(minLength: 0)

      //if variable that the button changes = true, show list
      if listIsShowing {
        //Your list
        List {
          Text("Your")
          Text("list")
          Text("appears")
          Text("When")
          Text("you")
          Text("click")
          Text("the")
          Text("button")
        }
        //Use below code if you want background to match the top section
        //.listStyle(.plain)
      }
    }
  }
}
```